# Lao font render blank on android 4.3 ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, internationalization

My app required two languages including Lao and English and I use i18n for localisation. I have customised font family style to lao language as the following:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'customfont';
 src: url('../lib/ionic/fonts/phetsarath.ttf') format("truetype");
}
body {
 font-family: 'customfont';
 font-size:30px;
}
```

It works on chrome but not on android device(Nexus 3) version 4.3. Any solutions to be able to render lao font in that android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. The best font format working in android 4.3 is svg.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'phetsarath_otecorner';
    src: url('font/phetsarath_ot.svg');
    src: url('font/phetsarath_ot.svg#phetsarath_otregular') format('svg'),
         url('font/phetsarath_ot.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/phetsarath_ot.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And apply the font-family as following.

```
body, .ionic-body {
  font-family: 'phetsarath_otecorner', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
  font-family: 'phetsarath_otecorner', sans-serif;
} 

.tab-item {
   font-family: 'phetsarath_otecorner', sans-serif;
}

input, button, select, textarea {
   font-family: 'phetsarath_otecorner', sans-serif;
}

.roboto {
   font-family: 'phetsarath_otecorner', sans-serif;
}
.roboto input {
   font-family: 'phetsarath_otecorner', sans-serif;
}
```